# In vSphere Client how can you search for a machine by it's name?

Tags: vmware, search

In vSphere I've got a lot of virtual machines to manage and am looking for a way to search by the name I gave the VM when I created it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> doesn't do anything. If I click on the pane the VMs are in and start typing a name, the first letter matches but the second letter always matches a new name (unlike Windows Explorer where when you type <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> it finds **foo**, not swtiches between files starting with **f**, **o** and another **o**).

Comment: I'm I right in thinking your connecting to the host directly and not via vcenter?

Comment: @Rqomey I am not skilled with these tools all I know is I start VMWare vSphere Client and that's the program I use.

Comment: When you start the client you usually put in a name/ipaddress, username and password. Is the ip address you put in pointing to an ESXi host, or to a vcenter